# Rainbow Table, compromised Geth Node and any possible recourse

Tags: go-ethereum

If and/or when a geth node is compromised, and the hacker uses a rainbow table, will he or she be able to get many private keys to sign his/her way to be the king of ether?

Comment: In fact private keys in geth are almost unprotected.  Regardless of how many rounds of encryption were used, this encryption only protects keys stored on disk.  Once read into memory and decrypted, keys become accessible to everyone who may access the node via RPC.  Taking into account, that RPC is not protected at all by itself, everybody who may open TCP connection to the node may basically steal your assets.

Answer (score 1):

If a ethereum node is compromised the only possibility to leak private keys is if they are unencrypted on disk, or if the user send the password to unlock them.

For example geth stores the private keys encrypted with 200k rounds of scrypt, so using rainbow tables is not feasible.

Comment: the keys are by default encrypted right? Can locked accounts still be compromised?

Comment: Only if the user tries to unlock them, because it will need to send the password.